# Error: The attribute "Returns" in element <Target> is unrecognized

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis, yetanotherforum

em trying to open yaf v1.9.5 solution targeting VS 2008, but an error occurred while opening yaf solution in VS 2008:

Unable to read the project file 'YAF.Classes.Core.csproj'.

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(132,9): The attribute "Returns" in element  is unrecognized.

Unable to read the project file 'DNA.csproj'.

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(132,9): The attribute "Returns" in element  is unrecognized.

.
.
. 
an finally

One or more projects in the solution could not be loaded for the following reason(s):

The application for the project is not installed.

These projects will be labeled as unavailable in Solution Explorer. Expand the project node to show the reason the project could not be loaded.

please help me if possible.

Thanks
Lucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Visual Studio 2008 SP1 so that Web Application Project (WAP) is installed.

[Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Download from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)